# jQuery to sequentially apply CSS styles

Tags: jquery, css, sequence

I'm currently using a jQuery function to randomly assign one of a list of background colors to every element which has one of a list of CSS classes assigned to it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ['color1', 'color2', 'color3'];
    $('.class1, .class2').each(function () {
        var hue = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        $(this).css("background-color", hue);
    });
});
```

I would like to alter the function so that instead of assigning the colors at random, it assigns them in sequence, looping back to the beginning of the color array when there are more elements to assign colors to than colors to assign, i.e.:

```
<element1 class="class1" style="background-color: color1;"></element1>
<element2 class="class2" style="background-color: color2;"></element2>
<element3 class="class1" style="background-color: color3;"></element3>
<element4 class="class2" style="background-color: color1;"></element4>
<element5 class="class1" style="background-color: color2;"></element5>
```

Any suggestions as to where to start with this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe count the number of arrays, use a for loop on the classes then use a seperate counter and reset the counter when it equals the number of colours?

Comment: Thanks Liam. I'm not sure what you mean by counting the arrays though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colors = ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f'];
    var x = 0;
    $('.class1, .class2').each(function () {
        var hue = colors[x];
        x++;
        if (x == colors.length) {
            x = 0;
        }
        $(this).css("background-color", hue);
    });
});
```

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/FpPNW/1/)**

I didn't use a traditional for loop, but I made one myself by creating a variable `x` and adding it on `.each()`, and if it reaches the end of the color array I give it `0`(zero) value again to start over.

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: That's brilliant, and a lot more elegant than the solution I was trying to write! Thanks for your help :)